# How to get last insert id in Yii create page

Tags: php, yii

I have a model called `Invoice`.I have made necessary `CRUD for Invoice model`.The `attributes` for the Invoice model are as like `Invoice Title, Invoice No, Invoice Issue Date, Description`.Now I want that `when a user will redirect to invoice create page,the input field for Invoice No should be  automatically filled in the create page with last inserted id +1 and it should have prefix like INV:.So the input field for Invoice No should be like this INV:12.`By this a user don't need to fill the invoice no manually in increasing order.Here is the image for the create page.[image]

Comment: `$instance_of_your_model->primaryKey` will get last inserted model.

Comment: How to implement that in _form page?

Comment: This is not a good idea if the app is going to be multiuser.
Better option will be to not show this field at the create form(e.g. in _form.php show ID filed only if `!$model->isNewRecord`) and in _actionCreate_ change the redirect to the _update_ action (instead of the Yii's default _view_ action)

Comment: Suppose a user starts form/invoice A, and does not (yet) finish it. Then a user (either the same or a different one) opens the next form/invoice B, gets the same invoice-number and completes it. Next, the first user decides to finish form A... Now your database and/or your invoice-system is corrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all==>`This is not a good idea to store Invoice number dependent on table's unique id`

So you should insert last invoice number's number part+1 with text..

Now first get last invoice model then find its invoice number and populate the field..

In controller..

```
$model = new Invoice;

$last_invoice = Invoice::model()->find(array('order'=>'id DESC'));
$last_invoice_number = str_replace("INV:", "", $last_invoice->invoice_mumber);
$new_invoice_number = $last_invoice_number+1;

$model->invoice_number = "INV:".$new_invoice_number;

$this->render('create',array('model'=>$model));
```

**EDIT:**

Reason why `Yii::app()->db->lastInsertId)` cannot be used..

First as I said in first place its not good to dependent invoice id from unique id of table..second what if somebody inserted sonething in someother table in between..third what if the db connection is closed and started in between..

Comment: I think I have to use these codes in controller action create method or have to define separate?

Comment: yeah in controller actionCreate()

Comment: Ya its working..but..every time the invoice number is showing INV:2346.I want the last insert id+1 so that it will show the increasing id.

Comment: You don't have to do a new query per se. Your DB connection has a getLastInsertId function (Yii::app()->db->lastInsertId). Perhaps a bit easier in use if it applies to your case.

Answer (score 0):

Just a Suggestion:

If user does not need to fill the invoice number then why don't you just skip it from Display. I mean let not show it while creating. Once the form is submitted, you can show all the submitted value along the invoice number.

Once the form is submitted, you can display the invoice number simply by $model -> id; where id is the invoice number in the database.

You could use invoice number as the primary auto increment bigint value in the database. Then use INV: prefix while display.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Ujjwal for your nice suggestion.I am thinking to do all in that direction.Really thank for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple way to get last insert id in Yii.

```
            Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertId();
```